# Como declarar lista em classe?

Tags: java, classes, lista

Tenho uma classe `Usuario` que terá uma lista da classe `Pastas`, e essa classe terá uma lista da classe `Questão`.

```
public class Usuario{
     String nome; 
     ArrayList< Pasta > listaPasta;
}
```

O meu problema é não saber se essa colocação está certa, porque na minha cabeça, eu quero criar a classe `Usuario` e ter a lista criada, ou se eu tenho que criar por fora depois da criação da classe e dar um `SetListaPasta()`.

Comment: Use a formatação para código

Comment: Todo usuário criado já tem alguma pasta?

Comment: Sim dherik, essa seria a ideia. E consegui alcança-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não temos como saber porque não tem maiores informações na pergunta. Programar é menos escrever código e mais entender o problema e saber o que fazer (não como fazer).

Me parece que está correto assim, só deveria inicializar a lista, na forma atual ela está nula. Claro que pode inicializar no construtor também.

Pode ser que já coloque o valor da lista no construtor, ou pode adicionar os itens nele.

É possível ter um `SetListaPasta()`, mas quase sempre isto é um erro, faria algum sentido ter um método que adiciona pastas na lista. Mas talvez não seja o ideal. Depende do requisito que não sabemos.

Tudo é válido de acordo com a necessidade.

Comment: Eu não consigo mexer direito no stack ainda, é minha primeira pergunta, mas obg pela resposta!

Comment: Eu fiquei fazendo testes separados do meu código e resolvi da seguinte forma: Coloquei a instanciação dentro do construtor e fiz um método setListPasta(material), que recebia um objeto para ser adicionado na lista. E dentro do método ficou dessa forma: listPasta. Add(material).